# MS Access Error: Operation Must use an updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query I am trying to run.  Trying to fix a database issue.  I just wanted to copy one field from one table to another, based on the ids that link the two (not primary keys).  Simple stuff, not an SQL expert and rarely use access so this error puzzles me with this query:

```
UPDATE tblProvider
SET  tblProvider.groupname = (SELECT tblGroup.group
                     FROM tblGroup
                     WHERE tblGroup.groupid = tblProvider.groupid)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT tblGroup.group
              FROM tblGroup
              WHERE tblProvider.groupid = tblGroup.groupid);
```

I am not sure why it gives me the error unless this SQL I had a friend help with (who is a oracle guy) is not access sql flavor?   The database is on my machine windows locally.  It is pretty simple...not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Try to rename the column with reserved word "group"as name to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you could do it with a simple join:

```
UPDATE tblProvider INNER JOIN tblGroup
ON tblProvider.groupid = tblGroup.groupid
SET tblProvider.groupname = tblGroup.[group];
```

And yes, `group` is not a good choice for a column name.